# What are predictions with proper nouns in mahabharat and ramayan about kaliyug that have came true?

Tags: kali-yuga, pramana, evidence, future

***I want to know textual prediction about kaliyug with proper nouns(reffering to specific place like on xyz place,xyz incident will happen/nation) that have come true means have happened from valmiki ramayan Or mahabharat.***

Please don't include common predictions like increased hate,alcoholism, athiesm, killing of family by same family members.(like general ones)

I am looking for specific verses with specific persons/places or general verses with specific items etc.

Comment: Mahabharata and Ramayana are historical texts - not prediction books.

Comment: @User29449 you are right but they have few predictions for kaliyug in many verses Like people will migrate to nations with more barely and wheat. Athiesm will be practiced. Varna system deplete and many more like anti vedic acts. Family members will steal from same family

Comment: I don't need a superpower AGI to say that in the future people will follow the path with logic instead of ridiculous belief, globalization will occur, climate change will happen, and more frauds will occur. I don't get why one has to resort to a medieval-era text for such predictions, even a school-level kid can say the same. The only thing that doesn't change in change, so expecting changes in the future in different fields is what sort of high IQ thing. Ah.

Comment: Every geography of the world is tied to some ridiculous belief system where there are good gods and bad demons. To another part of geography, they appear differently and may sound ridiculous. When globalization happens at its peak, all this ridiculousness is supposed to die because people are going to be enlightened that belief system based on geography were myth.

Comment: @User29449 you need superpower to tell about future with proper nouns. If I cite source and say rape, murder, alcohol, adultery and athiesm will increase in kaliyug. But doing these with proper nouns and correctly is near to impossible without  .             .

Comment: I highly doubt if there is any Hindu text that does this with proper nouns. The Puranas had undergone multiple modifications to do that with proper nouns, this isn't same with others.

Comment: @User29449 can you choose one 1) all purans are written very late 2) purans were written early but modified 3-4 times

Comment: There were puranas that actually existed since the time of vedas as mythical stories. They are smiritis. Smiritis means the one written down from memory, so when being carryed from generation to generation they all got corrupt with time. Later during compilation, a lot of newer additions were added too that didn't actually existed in the original writings.

Comment: @User29449 I have one doubt let's suppose purans were modified then how could modification enter all over in India/world. Like 30 verses were added in Uttar Pradesh. How could it reach all over India?

Comment: Puranas were not decentralized texts, unlike Ramayana and Mahabharata. They were compiled in **centralized** authors called *vyasa*, what we don't know if this vyasa (meaning compiler) was a single person, or a group of people.

Comment: @User29449 Vishnu Puranas are authentic!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a verse with reference to father of buddha and buddha

Mahabharat shanti parva [Chapter 348](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D-12-%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5-348)

> कृत्वा भारावतरणं वसुधाया यथेप्सितम्।
>
> सर्वसात्वतमुख्यानां द्वारकायाश्च सत्तम।।  12-348-40
>
> करिष्ये प्रलयं घोरमात्मज्ञानाभिसंश्रयः।
>
> `द्वारकामात्मसात्कृत्वा समुद्रं गमयाम्यहम्।।  12-348-41
>
> ततः कलियुगस्यादौ द्विजराजतरुं श्रितः।
>
> भीषया मागधेनैव धर्मराजगृहे वसन्।। 12-348-42
>
> काषायवस्रसंवीतो मुण्डितः शुक्लदन्तवान्।
>
> शुद्धोदनसुतो बुद्धो मोहयिष्यामि मानवान्।। 12-348-43
>
> शूद्राः सुद्धेषु भुज्यन्ते मयि बुद्धत्वमागते।
>
> भविष्यन्ति नराः सर्वे बुद्धाः काषायसंवृताः।।  12-348-44
>
> Having done the desired relief of the burden of the earth.  O best of
> all the chiefs of the Satvatas and of Dwarka
>
> Relying on self-knowledge I shall cause a terrible annihilation  `I
> shall take Dwarka from myself and go to the sea.
>
> Then at the beginning of Kali Yuga he took refuge in the tree of the
> king of brahmins  He lived in the house of the king of righteousness
> in fear of Magadha
>
> He was dressed in brown clothes, shaved and had white teeth.  I, the
> ***Buddha, the son of Shuddhodana,*** shall bewitch men.
>
> The Sudras are enjoyed among the pure when I have attained
> Buddhahood.  ***All men will be enlightened and covered with
> saffron.***